# SSIS Script Task - Edit Script not working

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, vsta

This is a common recurring issue on Microsoft SSIS Projects development IDE on Visual Studio Community 2019 (Windows 10): given a Script Task the edit button that should open a Visual Studio Intance (VSTA) to work on C# code do not react to the click. There are plenty of threads on internet about this topic, which is very common each Visual Studio new upgrade or whatever:

- Upgrade VS to the latest version
- Upgrade Sql Server Integration Services Projects to the latest version
- Repair VSTA 2019 installation
- Upgrade Windows SO
- Uninstall and Install Sql Server Integration Service Projects

but this time none of the above is enough to solve. I am running VS 2019 Community 16.11.19 the latest version available as of today;

***UPDATE01: after reinstalling Sql Server Integration Service Projects a click on the edit button opens an instance of Visual Studio but it is empty, the code is not available

***UPDATE02: opened a thread on Microsoft Forum https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1030851/ssis-script-task-edit-script-not-working.html

Comment: Sorry I can't help I can only say this is one of many nails in the coffin of SSIS. It's complicated and unreliable

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties, and make sure right TargetServerVersion is set. It was set to SQL Server 2019 in my case, but I didn't have this version installed on my local computer. Since I only have SQL Server 2017 installed on my local computer, changing it to SQL Server 2017 solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suffer a lot from this problem so I want to tell you a concise and straightforward way to troubleshoot this even after installing all packages and extensions if it's not working then download visual studio tools application then install it and after installation they will ask you about restart don't ignore it, you have to restart it and then you will be able to access this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).